# regex based dataframe manipuation

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe, 'df' that looks like the attached image:

[image]

I need to extract only those rows which begin with a date since they are the only ones with an amount.
I tried :

```
statementtable=[]
for line in df:
if re.search('^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d',line):
    statementtable.append(line)
```

but it is throwing an error.

Comment: I think you have to make the 0 at the start optional `0?[1-9]` https://regex101.com/r/EGem7S/1

Comment: can you just not filter out rows without NaN in date column like: `df[df["date"].notnull()]` or in your case first column index.

Answer (score 0):

you need to not only add `?` it at the first zero on the day value suggested by "The fourth bird", but also add the second `?` at the month value so that when the month value has no zero digit (e.g. 11-8-2019) you can still capture it:

```
if re.search('^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d',line):
```

Comment: Sorry, I am getting TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object  in the re.search line.